# (401) Unauthorized error while accessing the Tenant details

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp

I am trying to access SharePoint tenant details and able to get an accessToken using Oauth2 flow.
then I used this token with CSOM to get tenant details as below.
but I get 401 error . is there any reason for this?  .

```
using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager(accessTokenScureString)
         .GetContext("https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com") )
         {
              Tenant tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
              var x = tenant.GetAppCatalog();
         }
```

Decoded token which has ***AllSites.FullControl*** scope

```
    {     
         
          "scp": "AllSites.FullControl User.Read User.Read.All",               
          "sub": "NXPMNfjX2HEBjxSWBhSof.........",
          "tid": "23e45f37-1111-2222-a601-........"
    
     }
```

Error

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'
```

Comment: Did you check below soultion? Please mark as answer if you are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

In order to use CSOM Core with Sharepoint Online you will require Sites.FullControl.All. and User.Read.All.

Please refer the below microsoft docs for more details.

[Grant Access Via Azure Ad](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

Please mark it as answer if solve you problem.